# SFML Not Loading Audio Files

Tags: c++, audio, sfml

I am currently working on a game using OpenGL and C++ and wanted to start using SFML to implement audio. After some library linking aggravation, I got everything set up. However, SFML will not load audio files like shown in the tutorials.

The pertinent code so far is simply this:

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
...
sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
buffer.loadFromFile("resources/LaserShot.wav"); // That is the correct directory
```

And I get this in our console output (the game continues normally)

```
Failed to open sound file "resources/LaserShot.wav" (couldn't open stream)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: "resources/LaserShot.wav" should be relative to your exe. Check you compilersettings where your exe gets executed and place the file accordingly.

Comment: @HannesHauptmann most IDE's project's relative path are the project folder

Answer (score 2):

> // That is the correct directory

No, it's not.

You can check the source here: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/src/SFML/Audio/SoundFileFactory.cpp#L74

The file was not found. Plain and simple.

Check your current directory and make sure your path is relative to that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you also have this in release folder? If you're running it in release mode it might not be able to find it if it's not in the release folder in a folder named the same